# log4shell POC : no HTTP redirect

Tags: java, log4j, log4shell

I am trying to understand/reproduce Log4shell vulnerability, using this [poc](https://github.com/kozmer/log4j-shell-poc) and also information from [Marshalsec](https://github.com/mbechler/marshalsec).

To do that, I've downloaded Ghidra v10.0.4, which is said (on Ghidra download page) to be vulnerable to log4shell. Installed it on an ubuntu VM, along with java 1.8 (as stated in POC), and loaded the Poc + marshalsec snapshot.

Tried to start Ghidra, it said java 11 was needed, so although I've installed java 1.8 I still downloaded java 11 and, when you start ghidra, it says the installed version is not good enough and ask for the path to a java11 version; so I just gave him path to the jdk11 directory and it seems happy with it. Ghidra starts alright.

Then set up my listener and launched the poc, got the payload string to copy/paste in ghidra, and got a response in the ldap listener saying it'll send it to HTTP. But nothing more. The end.

Since the HTTP server is set up by the same POC, I thought maybe I just couldn't see the redirection, so I started the http server myself, started the ldap server myself with marshalsec, and retried (see pics below for exact commands/outputs).

Setting http server:

[image: Set HTTP server]

Set listener:

[image: Set listener]

Setting LDAP server:

[image: Set LDAP server and get response]

Send payload string in Ghidra (in the help/search part, as shown in kozmer POC); immediately got an answer:
[image: Sending payload string in Ghidra]

I still receive a response on the LDAP listener (two, in fact, which seems weird), but nothing on the HTTP. The the Exploit class is never loaded in ghidra (it directly sends me a pop-up saying search not found, I think it is supposed to wait for the server answer to do that?), and I get nothing back in my listener.

Note that I don't really understand this Marshalsec/LDAP thing so I'm not sure what's happening here. If anyone have time to explain it will be nice. I've read lot of stuff about the vuln but it rarely goes deeply into details (most is like: the payload string send a request to LDAP server, which redirect to HTTP server, which will upload the Exploit class on the vulnerable app and gives you a shell).

Note: I've checked, the http server is up and accessible, the Exploit.class file is here and can be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Turned out for log4shell to work you need a vulnerable app and a vulnerable version of Java; which I thought I had, but nope. I had Java 11.0.15, and needed Java 11 (Ghidra need Java 11 minimum, only vulnerable version of Java 11 is the first one).

Downloaded and installed Java 11, POC working perfectly.